# Redirect Wordpress subfolder to index.php with .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

so I have site on Wordpress and inside main Wordpress directory I made catalog /w. So I have in main directory catalogs like

- w
- wp-content
- wp-admin
- ...

Inside /w I have catalogs /app and /public. Access to app is denied with .htaccess.
And now, inside /public I have files index.php and .htaccess. What I want to do is to redirect all urls from **mydomain.com/w/something/something2** to **mydomain.com/w/public/index.php**

Below is my .htacces inside /w/public

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /w/public
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

And now when I type url mydomain.com/w/something I got Wordpress 404 page. Hope some1 can help me :)

Comment: You need to add an exception for these paths starting with `w/` to WordPress’s own rewriting here, otherwise all requests for non-existing files will automatically be routed through WP’s own index.php.

Comment: Thanks man! Now its working :)